# Classes with virtually common code

Tags: c#, class, generics, collections

I have a number of custom collection classes. Each serves to provide a collection of various custom types - one custom type to one custom collection. The custom collections inherit `List<T>` [where T in this case is the specific custom type, rather then a generic] and provide some additional functionality.

I previously did away with the custom collections and had custom methods elsewhere, but I found as I extended the code that I needed the collections with their own methods.

It all works, everything is happy. But it irritates me, because I know I am not doing it properly. The issue is that each class uses pretty much the same code, varying only the type and a parameter, so I feel that it could be implemented as an abstract class, or generic, or extension to List, or ... but I'm not really understanding enough of the differences or how to go about it to be able to sort out what I need.

Here are two of my several collections, so that you get the idea:

```
    // JourneyPatterns
public class JourneyPatterns : List<JourneyPattern>
{
    private Dictionary<string, JourneyPattern> jpHashes;       // This is a hash table for quick lookup of a JP based on its values

    /* Add a journey pattern to the JourneyPatterns collection. Three methods for adding:
         1. "Insert Before" (=at) a particular point in the list. This is the method used by all three methods.
         2. "Insert After" a particular point in the list. This is "before" shifted by 1 e.g. "after 6" is "before 7"
         3. "Append" to the end of the list. This is "before" with a value equal to the list count, and is the same as inherited "Add", but with checks
    */
    public JourneyPattern InsertBefore(JourneyPattern JP, int before)
    {
        // check for a pre-existing JP with the same parameters (ignore ID). Do this by constructing a "key" based on the values to check against
        // and looking it up in the private hash dictionary
        JourneyPattern existingJP;
        if (jpHashes.TryGetValue(JP.hash, out existingJP)) { return existingJP; }
        else
        {
            // construct a new ID for this JP
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(JP.id)) JP.id = "JP_" + (Count + 1).ToString();
            // next check that the ID specified isn't already being used by a different JPS
            if (Exists(a => a.id == JP.id)) JP.id = "JP_" + (Count + 1).ToString();
            // now do the add/insert
            if (before < 0) { Insert(0, JP); } else if (before >= Count) { Add(JP); } else { Insert(before, JP); }
            // finally add to the hash table for fast compare / lookup
            jpHashes.Add(JP.hash, JP);
            return JP;
        }
    }
    public JourneyPattern InsertAfter(JourneyPattern JP, int after) { return InsertBefore(JP, after + 1); }
    public JourneyPattern Append(JourneyPattern JP) { return InsertBefore(JP, Count); }
}

// JourneyPatternSections
public class JourneyPatternSections : List<JourneyPatternSection>
{
    private Dictionary<string, JourneyPatternSection> jpsHashes;       // This is a hash table for quick lookup of a JPS based on its values

    /* Add a journey pattern section to the journeyPatternSections collection. Three methods for adding:
         1. "Insert Before" (=at) a particular point in the list. This is the method used by all three methods.
         2. "Insert After" a particular point in the list. This is "before" shifted by 1 e.g. "after 6" is "before 7"
         3. "Append" to the end of the list. This is "before" with a value equal to the list count, and is the same as inherited "Add", but with checks
    */
    public JourneyPatternSection InsertBefore(JourneyPatternSection JPS, int before)
    {
        // check for a pre-existing JPS with the same parameters (ignore ID). Do this by constructing a "key" based on the values to check against
        // and looking it up in the private hash dictionary
        JourneyPatternSection existingJPS;
        if (jpsHashes.TryGetValue(JPS.hash, out existingJPS)) { return existingJPS; }
        else
        {
            // construct a new ID for this JPS
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(JPS.id)) JPS.id = "JPS_" + (Count + 1).ToString();
            // next check that the ID specified isn't already being used by a different JPS
            if (Exists(a => a.id == JPS.id)) JPS.id = "JPS_" + (Count + 1).ToString();
            // now do the add/insert
            if (before < 0) { Insert(0, JPS); } else if (before >= Count) { Add(JPS); } else { Insert(before, JPS); }
            // finally add to the hash table for fast compare / lookup
            jpsHashes.Add(JPS.hash, JPS);
            return JPS;
        }
    }
    public JourneyPatternSection InsertAfter(JourneyPatternSection JPS, int after) { return InsertBefore(JPS, after + 1); }
    public JourneyPatternSection Append(JourneyPatternSection JPS) { return InsertBefore(JPS, Count); }
}
```

As you can see, what is differing is the type (JourneyPattern, or JourneyPatternSection), and the prefix that I am using for the "id" property of the type ("JP_" or "JPS_"). Everything else is common, since the method of determining "uniqueness" (the property "hash") is part of the custom type.

Some of my custom collections require more involved and different implementations of these methods, which is fine, but this is the most common one and I have implemented it about 6 times so far which seems a) pointless, and b) harder to maintain.

Your thoughts and help appreciated!

Comment: Make your classes implement some interface which contains properties "id" and "hash" and restrict type to that interface (class YourCollection<T> : List<T> where T: IYourInterface).

Comment: OK, I can see how that might work. Presumably I would also need the custom types to also implement another property in the interface e.g. "id_pfx" so that the collection knew what prefix to use for the id

Comment: Yes, or let collection itself store prefix, like answer below suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assming tha both `JourneyPattern` and `JourneyPatternSection` implements a common `interface` like:

```
public interface IJourney
{
    string hash { get; set; }
    string id { get; set; }
}
```

You can implements a base class for your collections:

```
public abstract class SpecializedList<T> : List<T> where T : class, IJourney
{
    private Dictionary<string, T> jpHashes;       // This is a hash table for quick lookup of a JP based on its values

    protected abstract string IdPrefix { get; }

    /* Add a journey pattern to the JourneyPatterns collection. Three methods for adding:
            1. "Insert Before" (=at) a particular point in the list. This is the method used by all three methods.
            2. "Insert After" a particular point in the list. This is "before" shifted by 1 e.g. "after 6" is "before 7"
            3. "Append" to the end of the list. This is "before" with a value equal to the list count, and is the same as inherited "Add", but with checks
    */
    public T InsertBefore(T JP, int before)
    {
        // check for a pre-existing JP with the same parameters (ignore ID). Do this by constructing a "key" based on the values to check against
        // and looking it up in the private hash dictionary
        T existingJP;
        if (jpHashes.TryGetValue(JP.hash, out existingJP)) { return existingJP; }
        else
        {
            // construct a new ID for this JP
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(JP.id)) JP.id = "JP_" + (Count + 1).ToString();
            // next check that the ID specified isn't already being used by a different JPS
            if (Exists(a => a.id == JP.id)) JP.id = IdPrefix + (Count + 1).ToString();
            // now do the add/insert
            if (before < 0) { Insert(0, JP); } else if (before >= Count) { Add(JP); } else { Insert(before, JP); }
            // finally add to the hash table for fast compare / lookup
            jpHashes.Add(JP.hash, JP);
            return JP;
        }
    }
    public T InsertAfter(T JP, int after) { return InsertBefore(JP, after + 1); }
    public T Append(T JP) { return InsertBefore(JP, Count); }
}
```

Then implement each collection:

```
public class JourneyPatterns : SpecializedList<JourneyPattern>
{
    protected override string IdPrefix => "JP_";
}

public class JourneyPatternSections : SpecializedList<JourneyPatternSection>
{
    protected override string IdPrefix => "JPS_";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. JourneyPatterns contain JourneyPatternSections (which in turn contain JourneyPatternTimingLinks) but there isn't a common ancestor. But thanks - neat solution, otherwise.

Comment: You can use an `interface` for both instead of a common ancestor.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the edit showing the `interface` implementation. That's excellent - just what I need, and gives me a good example of the uses of interfaces and abstraction.